# Using Requests and BeautifulSoup - Python returns tag with no text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to capture the number of visits on this page, but python returns the tag with no text.

This is what I've done.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://www.kijiji.ca/v-2-bedroom-apartments-condos/city-of-halifax/clayton-park-west-condo-style-luxury-2-bed-den/1016364514")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.find_all("span",{"class":"ad-visits"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you are trying to scrape are populated by javascript so `beautfulsoup` or `requests` aren't going to work in this case.

You'll need to use something like `selenium` to get the output.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.kijiji.ca/v-2-bedroom-apartments-condos/city-of-halifax/clayton-park-west-condo-style-luxury-2-bed-den/1016364514")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source , 'html.parser')
print soup.find_all("span",{"class":"ad-visits"})
```

`Selenium` will return the page source as rendered and you can then use `beautifulsoup` to get the value

```
[<span class="ad-visits">385</span>]
```

Comment: Does Python have to open Firefox to retrieve the infromation?

Comment: You can use firefox 'headless' or you can also use another webdriver with selenium but you need to have an environment where it will render the javascript.

Comment: What do you mean headless? How would your code change

Comment: Code stays the same, here's a post on running Firefox headless on Ubuntu with selenium http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/