# TLE from web page using lxml/requests (Python3.6.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, lxml

I'm trying to read a TLE set from this [link.](https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/ORDINAL/1/NORAD_CAT_ID/39090/orderby/TLE_LINE1%20ASC/format/tle)
The link comes from [Space-Track.org](https://www.space-track.org/#/tle)

I want read the link and create two variables, one for each line of the two line element in doing so. I did some searching and am trying to reuse the code from this thread [about reading a particular line from a web page in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248245/reading-a-particular-line-from-a-webpage-in-python). However, I'm not familiar with either requests or lxml. I tried running the code below:

```
<import numpy as np
from lxml import html
import requests

for nn in range(0,2):
    page = requests.get("https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/ORDINAL/1/NORAD_CAT_ID/39090/orderby/TLE_LINE1%20ASC/format/tleid=%" % nn)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    print (tree.xpath("//b/text()")[0])
>
```

And got the following traceback error:

```
<Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36-64\Projects\HTMLTLEREADER.py", line 19, in <module>
    page = requests.get("https://www.space-track.org/basicspacedata/query/class/tle_latest/ORDINAL/1/NORAD_CAT_ID/39090/orderby/TLE_LINE1%20ASC/format/tleid=%" % nn)
ValueError: unsupported format character 'A' (0x41) at index 115
>
```

I was initially trying to read both lines to check if the code ran on my version of python, hence range(0,2) for nn.

Any and all help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear:

```
ValueError: unsupported format character 'A' (0x41) at index 115
```

Index 115 of your string is here:

```
"...NORAD_CAT_ID/39090/orderby/TLE_LINE1%20ASC/format/tleid=%" % nn
                                           ↑
```

You're using percent-formatting but your string already contains percent signs for the unrelated percent-encoding in the URL. You can either double-escape your existing percent signs and fix your last format string:

```
"...NORAD_CAT_ID/39090/orderby/TLE_LINE1%%20ASC/format/tleid=%s" % nn
                                         ↑                    ↑
```

Or just concatenate the string:

```
"...NORAD_CAT_ID/39090/orderby/TLE_LINE1%20ASC/format/tleid=" + str(nn)
```

Comment: The newer string formatting is probably "best" for this and most similar cases!: `"{}".format(nn)`