# manipulating javascript code with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, dom-manipulation

I have html code embeded with java script code related to angular js. Later I realized that rows and columns of html code need to be inter cahnged. As I have bunch of html files so decided to use Python script. Have tried using BeautifulSoup 4.x. I could able to do interchange of rows and columns but while writing back to disk, it is noticed that few java script tags are missing.

My question is can I use beautiful soup for angular js code? if yes, code snippet would be extremely helpful.

Thanks

Comment: You may want to use one of Selenium's webdrivers (with PhantomJS or the browser you prefer) so that AngularJS code is actually executed and the changes to the DOM applied

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files.  You can't directly use it for angular js code.

Answer (score 1):

See this previous answer for a quick look at what some code using `Selenium` to get at the javascript might look like.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25985828/4147462