# Screen scraping tweets only returns 20 tweets

Tags: python, html, twitter

I tried scraping from the source page of a user's profile (input: username) using BeautifulSoup4.
 Here's my code:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import webbrowser

def getTweets(usrUrl):
    """Collects the tweets of passed @username and returns a list of tweets"""
    r = requests.get(usrUrl)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
    tweetStream = soup.find_all('ol', {'id': 'stream-items-id'})[0].find_all('li', {'data-item-type': 'tweet'})
    for tweetTree in tweetStream:
        try:
            tweetPTags = tweetTree.div.find('div', {'class':'content'}).find_all('p')
            tweets = []
            for tag in tweetPTags:
                tweets.append(tag.text)
        except:
            pass
    return tweets

usrNm = raw_input('Provide your username: @')
usrUrl = 'https://twitter.com/' + usrNm.lower()
followersUrl = usrUrl + '/followers'
usrTweets = getTweets(usrUrl)
for tweet in UsrTweets:
    print tweet
    print '\n'
```

However, I am not getting more than 20 tweets. I have tried going through previous similar questions, but could not really understand them much. I am trying not to use the Twitter API for it's rate limit, and personally, this is my first time scraping online, so I would like to do this without using 3rd party scrapers.

On inspecting the source page, this is what I observed. The stream of tweets are present as a list and the last two elements of the list are different from the other 18:

[Ordered List of tweets - before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fyfo.png) (Sorry, don't have a reputation of 10 so cannot post images here.)

However, when I scroll down to the last tweet, the page loads, more tweets automatically, and the source page now looks like this:
The square in red gets appended automatically into the source.

[Ordered List of tweets - after scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEJyL.png)

So I was wondering if the new stream of tweets had something to do with the last element of the tag: `<ol id="stream-items-id"></ol>` and indeed, it contains `js-no-dedup has-scroll-bump` which loads more tweets as the user scrolls down to the bottom.

Any workarounds to this problem? Your help is appreciated!

Souradeep

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` doesn't do anything with JavaScript

Comment: Any other package suggestions, @PeterWood?

Comment: A quick search will find you the Selenium + BeautifulSoup combination, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984782/using-requests-and-beautifulsoup-python-returns-tag-with-no-text

Comment: Wow. Thanks! @PeterWood

Comment: @user3566440 do you know that twitter as an api to retrieve data from it (has to register your app however) ?

Comment: @XavierCombelle OP says *'I am trying not to use the Twitter API for it's rate limit'*

Comment: @PeterWood: oh I missed this part. However if you don't respect the rate limit when scraping, you will finish by being blocked. So better being a good citizen.

Comment: @XavierCombelle: Using this only as an educational means. :) Thanks for the heads up, though!